# With twig how to store a variable inside html code

Tags: twig

Is there an equivalent to this in Twig :

```
<?php
   $a = 'hello';
   $b = '<h1>'.$a.'</h1>';

   echo $b;
?>
```

I try this but without success :

```
{% set a = 'hello' %}
{% set b = <h1>{{a}}</h1> %}
```

I'm new to twig and couldn't find a way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

To concatenate in Twig you need the tilda symbol, **~**

Eg.

```
{% set a = 'hello' %}
{% set b = '<h1>'~a~'</h1>' %}
```

Or you can use [string interpolation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#string-interpolation)
E.g.

```
{{ "<h1>{a}</h1>" }}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate and dump with the raw filter:

```
{% set a = 'hello' %}
{% set b = '<h1>' ~ a ~ '</h1>' %}

{{ b|raw }}
```

[Here](http://twigfiddle.com/xxrslq) a working solutions